# $? return different values in interactive vs in script

Tags: bash

the following shell funciton when run interactively, the result is correct ($?=0):

```
-bash-4.2$ run_task ()
{
    echo "$(date) - ALGOX_INTRADAY_CURRENT_DIR=$ALGOX_INTRADAY_CURRENT_DIR";
    ls $ALGOX_INTRADAY_CURRENT_DIR/* 2> /dev/null;
    echo "$(date) - \$?=$?"
}
-bash-4.2$ ALGOX_INTRADAY_CURRENT_DIR=/apps/alcr-lnx/homes/sacimso/algox-intraday/current/
-bash-4.2$ run_task
Fri Feb 25 09:53:27 EST 2022 - ALGOX_INTRADAY_CURRENT_DIR=/apps/alcr-lnx/homes/sacimso/algox-intraday/current/
/apps/alcr-lnx/homes/sacimso/algox-intraday/current//req_CHILE-KFWD-759645_1645797825292802.xml
Fri Feb 25 09:53:27 EST 2022 - $?=0
-bash-4.2$
```

however, when run in a larger script, it reported no files was in the directory:

```
Fri Feb 25 09:49:44 EST 2022 - ALGOX_INTRADAY_CURRENT_DIR=/apps/alcr-lnx/homes/sacimso/algox-intraday/current/
Fri Feb 25 09:49:44 EST 2022 - $?=2
```

my understanding is $? is the return code of the immediate previous statement, the return code should be the same as long ALGOX_INTRADAY_CURRENT_DIR points to the same path.
any idea why it yielded different result?

Comment: Remove `2> /dev/null;` and find out

Comment: Get rid of the I/O redirection so you can see the error message `ls` is providing.

Comment: Your script may have DOS line endings, in which case your path may end in a carriage return.//

Comment: Thanks both for the debugging tips. the behavior is not stable. I will watch for the error messages and update when find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by spaces in file names.
setting:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
```

resolved the issue